# Image is not saving in profile picture

Tags: android

This is the link which is used...http://javatechig.com/android/writing-image-picker-using-intent-in-android Problem is that images is not saving .When i am selecting picture it is coming in ImageView.but when I came out from this activity as well as from app ,it is not saving...Please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 pickImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

        switch(requestCode) { 
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                try {
                    final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need Sharedpreference to save the image so that when you resume the application/activity again it displays the image

Comment: Can You send the that code ..which can save my image.I have no much knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

1. Make global variable

   ```
   SharedPreferences sp;
   ```
2. In onCreate() after getting reference of your imageview

   ```
   sp=getSharedPreferences("profilePicture",MODE_PRIVATE);

   if(!sp.getString("dp","").equals("")){
       byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(sp.getString("dp", ""), Base64.DEFAULT);
       Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
   }
   ```
3. In onActivityResult method, after setting the image in imageView, write this code:

   ```
           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
           byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
           String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
           sp.edit().putString("dp", encodedImage).commit();
   ```

This code should work. Please try. If it does not work, i can give you full activity code.

Comment: Please Can You send full activity code ..so that i can improve my code properly

Comment: if it is working then you don't need full code, your code is better and efficient than mine :) :) All the best

Comment: Hey Prakhar when i am selecting the image from galley then selfie images are coming horizontally.i.e i take selfie of mine..and when i selct it for profile pic...my face coming horzontally

Comment: So can You help me to crop or something other while selcting So that its look will be better

Comment: @Manish I have never used crop functionality.. but there are tutorials available on web.. one I found is http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html.. You can try some more

Comment: Hi Prakahar..I solved out the the cropping part of image from the link...android:select image from gallery then crop that and show in an imageview...but i am not able to save imges in shared prefernce in this code

Answer (score 0):

what your doing is, your picking image from gallery and setting image to imageview using its bitmap. when you go out of activity, all view component attached to that activity also get destroy. 
One thing you have to understand here is, your not saving bitmap or image path for later appearance, by looking into your logic it is clearly indicate that saving and loading saved image is missing.

Solution is,

Save image path in shared preference once you pick image from gallery. try loading image from saved path, also please ensure image path is valid(in the sense, image is exist) before load it's bitmap to Imageview.

I hope you will achieve this.

Comment: Hi ..could i ask you to give voting, if you satisfied with my concerns.

Comment: When i am giving rating ..it shows once you have 15 repu ..it will publically show