# android:select image from gallery then crop that and show in an imageview...but not saving in sharedpreferce

Tags: android

This is the link which is used...[android:select image from gallery then crop that and show in an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490928/androidselect-image-from-gallery-then-crop-that-and-show-in-an-imageview)  Problem is that images is not saving .When i am selecting picture it is coming in ImageView.but when I came out from this activity as well as from app ,it is not saving...Please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  public class ImageSelecter extends Activity {

    private final int GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE=200;
    private final int RESULT_CROP = 400;

    public ImageView imageView;

 // static  String  picturePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_photo);

        Button  btn_choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select_image);

        btn_choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Start Activity To Select Image From Gallery
                Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
                startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
               // break;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                GalleryUtil.picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");
                //perform Crop on the Image Selected from Gallery
                performCrop(GalleryUtil.picturePath);
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP ) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                // Set The Bitmap Data To ImageView
                imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            }
        }
    }

    private void performCrop(String picUri) {
        try {
            //Start Crop Activity

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            File f = new File(picUri);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

            cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 280);

            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            // display an error message
            String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Supporting Class.

```
public class GalleryUtil extends Activity {

    private final static int RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE = 100;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "GalleryUtil";

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    File photoFile = null;

   static String picturePath;

    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
            //Pick Image From Gallery
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode){
            case RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE:

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    try{
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                       picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();



                        //return Image Path to the Main Activity
                        Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                        returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("picturePath",picturePath);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromGalleryIntent);
                        finish();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
                    Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                    finish();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to display image in image view after Crop?

Comment: From above code i am selecting image from galley and crop it and then set in imageview.But i want to save that cropped image in sharedprefernces also

Comment: Where is your saving code?

Comment: @saeed I want to save that cropped image in shared prefernces also because when i came out of the activity imageview doesnot show image

Comment: I dont know about that code...how to save a cropped image in shared prefernce

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18094829/3790150

Comment: @saeed I found saving code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300568/image-is-not-saving-in-profile-picture/36301361?noredirect=1#comment60228433_36301361..and as well as your sackoverflow...both are similar

Comment: But i dont know where i have to put in my activity i.e imageSelecter.For ImageselecterActivity go above

Comment: @saeed i have solved out thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Share preference cannot save the image, but you can save cropped image as a file, then save the file path to share preference as below.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putString("image_path", impage_path_string);
edit.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Get image from ImageView and convert it to String base64 or if u your saving in database then make field blob

```
   ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
            String userimage= Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

> now save image in sharepreferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_LOGIN, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                    editor.putString("USER_IMAGE",userimage);
editor.commit();
```

> now get image from sharepreferences

```
 String image=sharedPreferences.getString("USER_IMAGE", "IMAGE");


        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);


        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

> **now for**
>   start activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

> now for setimage to image view

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        try {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ddddd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imageUser.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```